# How to pass parameters to objective function when using minimize_scalar?

Tags: python, scipy

As explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html), to use scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar we need to define the objective function such as:

```
def f(x):
    return (x - 2) * x * (x + 2)**2
```

Then, we will optimize it by:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
res = minimize_scalar(f)
```

Now, I want to define my function with a variable to optimize and several parameters. For example, some thing like:

```
def f(x, a, b):
   return (x - a) * x * (x + a)**a + b
res = minimize_scalar(f(x, 2, 3))
```

How can I define the function and use it like that?
Please note that because a and b can be different each time, I cannot define them within the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`args`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html) argument:

> **args** *: tuple, optional*
>
> Extra arguments passed to the objective function.

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
res = minimize_scalar(f, args=(2, 3))
```

Comment: so how would it realize a is 2 and b is 3?

Comment: @Shabnam Exactly as in the code I posted. Each element in the `args` tuple is passed as one argument after `x`.